# Enterprise Architect with SVN

Tags: uml, tortoisesvn, enterprise-architect

I am currently working on a software that consists of numerous components (around 10,000 files) that does not use a Version Control System. My mission is to create a graphical representation (UML) of all the deposits of data and their links, using Enterprise Architect, thereby organizing and linking them to an SVN Repository. I want to know if it is possible to use this tool (EA) to connect this representation of data deposits with SVN.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So your question is: can I show the deployment of svn with EA?

Comment: Not just show the deployment, but also to establish a link with SVN.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "establish a link". Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Sure it is possible to integrate EA with Version Control. As fisrt step- read the following [PDF](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/WhitePapers/Version_Control.pdf) More details can be found in the 'Deployment of Enterprise Architect' whitepaper from [this](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/whitepapers/) list. During raeding, put attention and consider the limits.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Say I have a folder 'Sample' with files A, B, and C in the SVN repository. I represent these files using a package diagram with Enterprise Architecture. I want to know if it is possible to have access to these files in the repository by clicking the diagram.

Comment: In simple words, is it possible to create hyperlinks to the files in the SVN repository?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. By adding a hyperlink to your diagram you can open files or directories

[image]

(and quite a bit more)
[image]

Comment: Okay thank you very much :)